# regarding installation of ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot

My pc has 1GB RAM and I am trying to install ubuntu 14.04 32 bit by running .iso file from windows xp 32 bit. It always gives me error called' cannot download metalink and hence the iso file'
I hv downloaded 3 to 4 new iso files from ubuntu website but still it gives me the same error.
This didnt happened previously when I use to install it on my same pc...
Plz..help

Comment: Could it be [this bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202217/wubi-installer-cant-find-metalink)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have a good internet connection? It could be that your internet keeps going out during the download. You could also ditch Wubi and grab the ISO from the Ubuntu website and then create a live CD/USB, up to you.

Comment: Actually I downloaded iso file first. ..then I runned wubi file from my system